# SQL statement to select pivottable data from excel?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, excel

I know that in VB .NET there are a few different ways to import data from an excel workbook. The first method is to load the excel dll as a reference, open the file, and then call out cells / ranges from there.  The second method I have seen is to use queries that are formulated as SQL statements to which the data can be accessed without opening the workbook.

I am interested in the second method which I can do perfectly fine which is outlined here pretty well:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim filepath As String = "C:\Users\wzcj9x\Desktop\database layout.xlsx"
    Dim m_sConn1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & filepath & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"

    '========================================================
    'Use a DataSet to read data from the InventoryData table.
    '========================================================
    Dim conn1 As New OleDbConnection(m_sConn1)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn1)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    MsgBox(dt(0)(0).ToString)
    ' DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

    conn1.Close()
End Sub
```

Now my question is, does anyone know how to retrieve data from a pivot table through a query method like this one?  I don't want to open the excel file. The query method is **a lot** faster and doesn't leave resources hanging.

My pivot table that I am referencing does not have data residing somewhere else on the workbook which is why it is tricky. It is a file someone else creates once a day and I believe they populate the data from somewhere else.  I do know if I double click on the bottom right corner of the pivot table, it will then generate a new tab and display the data but this of course requires opening the workbook.

If anyone has any advice even if it isn't a full solution, I would greatly appreciate it!  I am hoping for an answer in vb .net but if there is one in C#, I suppose that would work too; however, I believe the answer is more around the excel side than the programming language.

**Update**

Really all I need is to determine the correct SQL statement to retrieve data from a pivot table.

Comment: have you seen this? http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/06/28/create-pivottable-reports-with-vbnet/

Comment: @coder32 Helpful and I will try with that but still perhaps someone has an example of reading from one as well.  I get the idea of creating one but am struggling with the SQL statement to read from it.